# jQuery UI tabs breaks after upgrade to 1.9.2

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

On upgrading from jquery ui 1.6 to 1.9.2, the tabs functionality that was working perfectly, is now broken! The tabs are not even visible anymore. I checked the html markup between the "good" and the "broken" pages, and there is no difference.

I have a plugin called livequery that is outdated and may be the cause for this. In addition, I have a bunch of bindings that have deprecated syntax. I updated all the deprecated code, as best as I knew how based upon jquery ui upgrade guide. None of it worked though. Could someone who's faced this issue kindly share their insights? My "upgraded" jquery ui tabs code is as follows:

```
var Tabs = {
    init: function() {
        this.tabs = this.getTabs();
        this.on();
    },
    getTabs: function() {
        return jQuery(this.tabNode()).tabs({
            //ajaxOpts deprec
            //ajaxOptions: { global: false },
            beforeload: function(event, ui) {
                ui.ajaxSettings.global = false;
            },
            //select deprec
            //select: function() { jQuery('#waitmsg').activate() },
            option: function() {
                jQuery('#waitmsg').activate()
            },
            load: function() {
                jQuery('#waitmsg').hide()
            }
        });
    },
    tabNode: function() {
        return '#schools_tab > ul';
    },
    on: function() {
        this.onHighSchoolTab();
        this.onMidSchoolTab();
        this.onElemSchoolTab();
    },
    selected: function() {
        return this.tabs.data('selected.tabs');
    },
    refreshSelected: function() {
        jQuery(this.tabNode()).tabs('load', this.selected());
    },
    refreshIfSelected: function(index) {
        if (this.selected() == index) {
            jQuery(this.tabNode()).tabs('load', index);
        }
    },
    handleError: function(request) {
        eval(request.responseText);
    },
    // grab the last element of the id of an element.
    parseID: function(el) {
        return el.id.split('_').pop();
    },
    get: function(xfa, accountID, context) {
        $j.get('index.cfm', {
            fuseaction: xfa,
            accountID: accountID,
            context: context
        }, null, 'script');
    },
    post: function(href, data, callback) {
        if (!data) data = {};
        if (!callback) callback = null;
        $j.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            href: href,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: callback,
            error: function(request) {
                // evaluate alert from error block, ignore errors
                try {
                    eval(request.responseText);
                } catch (err) {}
            }
        });
    },
    // define each tab binding
    onHighSchoolTab: function() {
        FormBinder.on('hischools');
        $j('#school_context input').livequery('click', function() {
            var context = $j(this).val();
            Tabs.get('hischools.list', Tabs.parseID(this), context);
            // Update the new note link to reflect the context change
            var link = $j('#new_schoollist').prop('href');
            $j('#new_schoollist').prop('href', link.replace(/context=\w+/, 'context=' + context));
        });
        $j('#show_all_schools').livequery('click', function() {
            Tabs.post(this.href, {}, function(data, textStatus) {
                $j('#show_all_schools').hide();
            });
            return false;
        });
        $j('#school_list a.delete').livequery('click', function() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this school?')) {
                Tabs.post(this.href);
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Blowsie, jquery 1.9.1 & jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js (with all the required widgets including tabs). I did a console.log($.ui.tabs), and the debugger displays [object Object], meaning tabs is being loaded. The darn thing just won't display the tabs though!

Comment: the question states you are using 1.9.2 maybe you should start over and implement your code line by line, also you consider using the jq migration tool if required. This is pretty simple stuff. Also people are much more liekly to answer your question if you put it on jsfiddle

Comment: My mistake, it is 1.9.2. It was my understanding that the migration tool is only useful if upgrading from v1.6 and later. I'm upgrade from 1.2.6 to 1.9.1 & from 1.6 to 1.9.2 (UI).

Comment: I think I've isolated the issue to the livequery plugin, which is completely outdated. I was wondering if I could replace using the plugin entirely, by instead leveraging jquery 1.9 .on() or .delegate() functionality? this is the plugin: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery